# How to stop dnsmasq from adding ISP DNS servers to a VPN connection?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, dnsmasq

This is Ubuntu 15.10. The following lines from the log happen when connecting to the VPN:

```
dnsmasq[983]    setting upstream servers from DBus
dnsmasq[983]    using nameserver 1xx.xxx.xx.xx#53 <-- VPN DNS 1 (set in the VPN connection only)
dnsmasq[983]    using nameserver 1xx.xxx.xx.xx#53 <-- VPN DNS 2 (set in the VPN connection only)
dnsmasq[983]    using nameserver 2xx.xx.xx.xxx#53 <-- ISP DNS 1 (set in the regular wired connection only)
dnsmasq[983]    using nameserver 2xx.xx.xx.xxx#53 <-- ISP DNS 2 (set in the regular wired connection only)
```

I don't want the last two items to be happening.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/768801) doesn't work for me, as I already have resolvconf installed and when I say "set" above, I mean explicitly specified.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> > A full explanation is posted here: [Why is dnsmasq adding ISP DNS servers to a VPN connection and how do I stop it? by danielkza](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/46i641/why_is_dnsmasq_adding_isp_dns_servers_to_a_vpn/d05g2ct).
>
> NetworkManager uses a local DNS forwarder using dnsmasq by default. In
>   that case, it sets up a "split DNS" where only queries for the domains
>   belonging to the VPN space go to the VPN DNS, and others get directed
>   to where they would go if no VPN was being used
>   ([source](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2014-October/msg00082.html))
>   If you want to eliminate that behaviour and have the VPN DNS used in
>   all cases, you have to disable the local forwarder by
>   removing/commenting the `dns=dnsmasq` line in
>   `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, then reloading/restarting
>   NetworkManager.